# Linking JS file from www subdirectory for R shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a `script.js` file in the `www` subdirectory, which is located in the same directory as my `app.R` file.

Inside the `app.R` file, I have something like this:

```
header <- ...

sidebar <- ...

body <- dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$script(src='script.js')), ...)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) { ... }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But once this is launched in my browser (locally), it says it cannot find the `script.js` file. Indeed, if I open the Developer Tools in Chrome, I don't see the `www` subdirectory or anything under the `Sources` tab.

I thought the `www` directory should be automatically recognized by Shiny? I'm not sure if it has something to do with this being tested locally (versus published on **shinyapps.io**?)... or am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strange, that indeed should work. Are you sure your file is named `script.js` ? I don't see any other possible reason.

Comment: post a screenshot of the app directory tree with the script please

Comment: I think this is a bug of `shiny 1.3.1`. Try to downgrade.